# Convert business hours from timezone to another?

Tags: php, laravel, timezone

I'm using PHP/Laravel/Carbon.

I have a list of business hours, is it possible to convert them from timezone to another ?

I have something like :

```
Timezone = Jordan/Amman 
Day number = 3 (Wednesday)
Hour = 7:00 (24 hour system)
```

Convert it to something like :

```
Timezone = America/New_York 
Day number = ??
Hour = ??
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into how to use PHP's [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects with different formatting and [DateTimeZone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)s.

Example:

```
<?php

$tz_src = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Amman');
$tz_dst = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');

$date = new DateTime('next wednesday 5:00', $tz_src);

// 2019-07-24 05:00 (Asia/Amman)
printf("%s (%s)\n", $date->format('Y-m-d H:i'), $date->getTimezone()->getName());

$date->setTimezone($tz_dst);

// 2019-07-23 22:00 (America/New_York)
printf("%s (%s)\n", $date->format('Y-m-d H:i'), $date->getTimezone()->getName());
```

Comment: Perfect! you put me on the right direction, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
 $date=new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York') );
```